# Wait for the hidden class to be deleted from the element in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a puppeteer script
There is a div that has a hidden class
This class is deleted after a few minutes and the div becomes visible
I can select the div but can't click on it until the hidden class is deleted
How do I make it wait until it delete this class from the div ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.waitForFunction`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args). It repeatedly runs specific function in page context and returns a Promise that resolves when this functions returns a truthly value. Provide it with a function that returns truthly value when your target div doesn't have that class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend,
I tried this code but it doesn't work, do you know how it should be written? Thank you very much. 
await driver.waitForFunction("document.querySelector(Selector) && document.querySelector(Selector).classList.value != 'hidden' ");

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => !document.querySelector('div .hidden_class'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply my friend,
When the time comes, the hidden class moves from one element to another, but it is not deleted from the code